# Query string not redirected on deeper level directories

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect each link with a query string to a specific address by appending the string. I have the following in my WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) catid%1? [R=301,L]
```

When a user hits `example.com/?catid=10`, they are successfully redirected to `example.com/catid10`, which is what I want.

However, when they go a directory deeper (`example.com/category/?catid=10`), they are not redirected to `example.com/category/catid10`.

I have been reading manuals but can't find the answer.

**Edit**

If this is helpful, this is what WordPress has defined in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing `RewriteBase /` is already defined (which it normally is with WordPress and must be if your existing redirect is working) then you can do it like the following with a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)catid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ $1/catid%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The capturing group `(.*?)` is non-greedy so does not consume the optional trailing slash that follows.

Requests for the document root do not require `RewriteBase`, but all "deeper" URLs do, since the resulting *substitution* string will otherwise be a *relative* URL.

The non-capturing `(?:^|&)` prefix on the *CondPattern* ensures that it only matches the URL parameter name `catid` and not `foocatid` etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `RewriteBase /` is defined. I tried this, still doesn't redirect.

Comment: @vl4der You need to put this at the top of the `.htaccess` file, _before_ the existing WordPress directives.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the captured group from `(.*)` to your redirect target using `$1`.  I'd break it up into a few rules so that you don't get duplicated slashes.  Rather then ending your rewrite targets with a question mark, I would add the `QSD` (query string discard) flag to the rule.  I would also add starts with (`^`) and ends with (`$`) to rewrite rule so you always match the whole thing.   I also like to start my rules with an optional slash (`/?`) so that the rules can be used in both .htaccess and apache conf.

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# Home URL with catid query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /catid%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

# Deep URL ending in slash with a catid query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ /$1/catid%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

# Deep URL not ending in slash with a cadid query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1/catid%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```